# Add handle to sortable element in Angular4 (ng2-dnd)

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I would like to use [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) in my Angular4 app, to create a sortable list. There is an example in the readme "Add handle to restrict draggable zone of component", but if I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DraggableHandleComponent -> DraggableComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DraggableHandleComponent -> DraggableComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DraggableComponent!
```

How is it possible to provide that component? It is not mentioned in the readme.
I can only avoid the error, if I remove `dnd-draggable-handle` attribute from the element.

---

This is the example code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-dnd-handle',
    template: `
<h4>Simple Drag-and-Drop with handle</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Available to drag</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>
                            <span dnd-draggable-handle>=</span>&nbsp;
                            Drag Handle
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-info" (onDropSuccess)="simpleDrop=$event">
            <div class="panel-heading">Place to drop</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div *ngIf="simpleDrop">Item was dropped here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
})
export class SimpleDndHandleComponent {
    simpleDrop: any = null;
}
```

Comment: I got the same error when I used the `dnd-draggable-handle` instead of `dnd-sortable-handle`. The error was gone but I could not sort the items (by grabbing the `span` handle nor the `li` item itself) :-(

Answer (score 0):

dnd-draggable-handle must be in the children elements of dnd-droppable element. In your case, dnd-droppable-handle is outside.